# Download file from s3 without write it to file system in nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, stream

I have a Nodejs server running with Hapi.

one of the job of the server is to send files to servicer API (the API only accept streams when I send buffer it return an error) on the user ask

All the files are stored in s3.
When I download them if I'm using promise(), 
I get in the body buffer.
And I can get passthrough if I'm using createReadStream().

My problem is when I try to convert the buffer to stream and send it the API reject it, and the same when I use the createReadStream() result,
but when I use FS to save the file and then FS to read the API accept the stream and its work.

so I need help how can I create the same result without saving and reading the file.

edit:
here is my code I know it's the wrong way but it works I need a better way that will work

```
static async downloadFile(Bucket, Key) {
    const result = await s3Client
      .getObject({
        Bucket,
        Key
      })
      .promise();
    fs.writeFileSync(`${Path.basename(Key)}`,result.Body);

    const file = await fs.createReadStream(`${Path.basename(Key)}`);
    return file;
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

If I understand it correctly, you want to get the object from the s3 bucket and stream to your HTTP response as the stream.

Instead of getting the data in the buffers and than figuring out the way to convert it to stream can be complicated and has its limitations, if you really want to leverage the power of streams then don't try to convert it to buffer and load the entire object to the memory, you can create a request that streams the returned data directly to a Node.js Stream object by calling the createReadStream method on the request.

Calling createReadStream returns the raw HTTP stream managed by the request. The raw data stream can then be piped into any Node.js Stream object.

This technique is useful for service calls that return raw data in their payload, such as calling getObject on an Amazon S3 service object to stream data directly into a file, as shown in this example.

```
//I Imagine you have something similar.
server.get ('/image', (req, res) => {
    let s3 = new AWS.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01'});
    let params = {Bucket: 'myBucket', Key: 'myImageFile.jpg'};
    let readStream= s3.getObject(params).createReadStream();
    // When the stream is done being read, end the response
    readStream.on('close', () => {
        res.end()
    })

    readStream.pipe(res);
});
```

When you stream data from a request using createReadStream, only the raw HTTP data is returned. The SDK does not post-process the data, this raw HTTP data can be directly returned.

**Note:**
Because Node.js is unable to rewind most streams, if the request initially succeeds, then retry logic is disabled for the rest of the response. In the event of a socket failure, while streaming, the SDK won't attempt to retry or send more data to the stream. Your application logic needs to identify such streaming failures and handle them.

**Edits:**
After the edits on the original question, I can see that s3 sends a PassThrough stream object which is different from a FileStream in Nodejs. So to get around the problem use the memory (If your files are not very big and or you have enough memory).

Use the package `memfs`, it will replace the native `fs` in your app
https://www.npmjs.com/package/memfs

Install the package by `npm install memfs` and require as follows:

```
    const {fs} = require('memfs');
```

and your code will look like

```
 static async downloadFile(Bucket, Key) {
        const result = await s3
        .getObject({
          Bucket,
          Key
        })
        .promise();
      fs.writeFileSync(`/${Key}`,result.Body);

      const file = await fs.createReadStream(`/${Key}`);
      return file;
    }
```

Note that the only change I have made in your functions is that I have changed the path `${Path.basename(Key)}` to `/${Key}`, because now you don't need to know the path of your original filesystem we are storing files in memory. I have tested and this solution works

Comment: my problem is that I need to get the stream to formData to send to other API like this  => ```file[0] =  readStream, file[1]=readStrean```

Comment: @YotavMasa can you than post the code how are you doing with FS ? I can than update my answer with the solution

Comment: @YotavMasa check my answer, hopefully it helps you

Comment: but if I have the buffer with the data don't, I have an option to make it stream without saving the file?

Comment: @YotavMasa you can but the stream type will be the not acceptable type for the API. 
It has to be a FileStream which required by the API because it expects information about files like file stats and meta, if you can transform the Passthrough stream to FileStream on the fly "Which is not an easy task" than you can send the stream directly, that's why MemoryFS is perfect since it is kind of transforming the passthrough stream to FileStream.

Comment: If you read the code of MemoryFS it is actually using buffers to create the correct type of stream. So you don't have to reinvent the wheel because when you run the `fs.writeFileSync(`/${Key}`,result.Body);` it saves your files in buffers array and when you run `createReadStream` it converts the buffers to FileStream.